# Executing Function in Django Template with button OnClick

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is a filter in my `Django Templates tag`.

```
@register.filter('saving_bookmarks_db')
def saving_bookmarks_db(news_data,news_source,):
    #this will save the data in db
```

In my `Django Template`, i have one button like this

```
<button data-toggle="modal" id="myClickButton" href="#dbModal" class="btn btn-info pull-right custom" >Bookmark</button>
```

this is my include command, which will include modal html and save the also save the data using tag

```
{% include "db_saving.html"  with source=source data=data %}
```

All i want to do is that, this include command execute only when the button is click but in django whenever the page is refresh, it save all the data in the DB and not the one when i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do things like this in a template filter. That will always be executed on render.

Anything that affects the database in response to user action can only happen in a view, accessed via a URL. It sounds like you want that to be called from an Ajax function in your template which in turn is called from your onclick handler.

Comment: So the only and best solution is that i call a view with that button and save the data from that view?

Comment: Yes, that is always the thing to do.

Comment: what if i want to return a dictionary from django template to view? i need to use extra feature like ajax or it can be done simply?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. I already said you should probably use Ajax, but I'm not sure what you're asking about dictionaries.

Comment: @Rao there's no such thing as "returning" something from a template. If you want to do web development, you _must_ understand the HTTP request/response cycle, and then how Django's views and templates fit into this cycle - then you'll understand why thye concept of "returning a dict from a template to a view" makes no sense at all ;)